# INNERJOIN + SELECT specific column

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a little problem with my SQL request, I checked many subject about this problem but I didn't find how to resolve.

My table `images` and `plaquettes` got both 'domaine' column but I want select only from the `plaquettes` table. This sql return me a FetchAll error.

I don't know why this simple INNER JOIN doesn't work.
Thanks for helping

```
 <?php 
  $sqlimg = "SELECT *, plaquettes.domaine AS  plaquettedomaine FROM images INNER JOIN plaquettes ON images.id = plaquettes.images_id";
    $resultsimg = $connexion->query($sqlimg);
    $plaquettesimg = $resultsimg->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 foreach($plaquettesimg as $pimg) { ?>
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pimg->name ?>" name="delete_img" >
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pimg->plaquettedomaine ?>" name="delete_domaine" >
 <?php } ?>
<button onclick="return confirm('Voulez vous vraiment supprimer cette plaquette ?')" type="submit" class="btn pull-left btn-danger" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $p->id ?>">Supprimer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Declare your tables properly, don't use SELECT *

Comment: You mean, i do like `SELECT images.name AS imgname, plaquettes.domaine AS  plaquettedomaine` ?

Comment: Yep, give that a go.

Comment: Arf that return this again `Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean`,  did my INNERJOIN is good ? If i delete all the non required content i got this `SELECT * FROM images INNER JOIN plaquettes ON images.id = plaquettes.images_id` and with just this i got an error :/

Comment: `var_dump($connexion->errorInfo());` after `$connexion->query($sqlimg)` to see what the exact error is.

Comment: Hm its look like my request dont know `plaquettes.images_id` i have this 
`array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42S22" [1]=> int(1054) [2]=> string(52) "Unknown column 'plaquettes.images_id' in 'on clause'" }`

Comment: Okay, so obviously that column doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, plaquettes.domaine AS  plaquettedomaine FROM images INNER JOIN plaquettes ON images.id = plaquettes.images_id
```

Should be something like this

```
SELECT p.*, p.domaine AS  plaquettedomaine
FROM
    images i
    INNER JOIN plaquettes p
    ON i.id = p.images_id
```

Note I am using table aliases to make it easier to follow and less typing.  To alias a table simply put a space after the table name and the desired alias.

The reason you were getting all columns is becuase of "`*`".  That will return everything for both tables.  So by switching to `p.*` you limit that to all columns from `plaquettes`.  Note in most situations it is not considered good code to use`*` because of potential schema changes in your underlying tables will more than likely break your application.  You should list out the specific columns you want. `p.Id, p....`